# How to return only one closest value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, which looks like this:

| aircraft | flight | check_schedule | next_flight_schedule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boeing | 123 | 10.02.2022 21:00 | 11.02.2022 14:30 |
| Boeing | 234 | 10.02.2022 19:00 | 11.02.2022 22:50 |
| Boeing | 345 | 10.02.2022 21:00 | 11.02.2022 04:30 |
| Airbus | 789 | 21.02.2022 16:30 | 22.02.2022 01:20 |
| Airbus | 890 | 21.02.2022 22:30 | 22.02.2022 02:20 |

I need to extract only one row with the closest 'next_flight_schedule' that happened after 'check_schedule'. Like this:

| aircraft | flight | check_schedule | next_flight_schedule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boeing | 345 | 10.02.2022 21:00 | 11.02.2022 04:30 |
| Airbus | 789 | 21.02.2022 16:30 | 22.02.2022 01:20 |

One column for each aircraft, but with the smallest date which happened after check_schedule. All columns should be displayed in the query.

Comment: You want the smallest [interval](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7690645A-0EE3-46CA-90DE-C96DF5A01F8F) between columns `check_schedule` and `next_flight_schedule`, correct?

Comment: I need smallest value from ‘next_flight_schedule’ for each aircraft

Comment: Do you mean: `SELECT aircraft, MIN(next_flight_schedule) FROM table GROUP BY aircraft` ?

Comment: Can you try this?

SELECT aircraft as a, flight, check_schedule, 
(SELECT MIN(next_flight_schedule) FROM table WHERE aircraft=a) next_flight
FROM table
GROUP BY aircraft

Answer (score 0):

One option might be this (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with test (aircraft, flight, check_schedule, next_flight_schedule) as
  2  -- sample data
  3  (select 'Boeing', 123, to_date('10.02.2022 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('11.02.2022 14:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4   select 'Boeing', 234, to_date('10.02.2022 19:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('11.02.2022 22:50', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  5   select 'Boeing', 345, to_date('10.02.2022 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('11.02.2022 04:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  6   select 'Airbus', 789, to_date('21.02.2022 16:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('22.02.2022 01:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  7   select 'Airbus', 890, to_date('21.02.2022 22:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('22.02.2022 02:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  8  ),
  9  --
```

---

```
 10  temp as
 11  -- MAX CHECK_SCHEDULE per aircraft
 12  (select aircraft, max(check_schedule) max_check_schedule
 13   from test
 14   group by aircraft
 15  )
 16  select t.*
 17  from test t join temp a on a.aircraft = t.aircraft
 18  where t.next_flight_schedule =
 19                                 -- the 1st NEXT_FLIGHT_SCHEDULE that follows the MAX CHECK_SCHEDULE
 20                                (select min(t1.next_flight_schedule)
 21                                  from test t1
 22                                  where t1.aircraft = t.aircraft
 23                                    and t1.next_flight_schedule > a.max_check_schedule
 24                                 );

AIRCRA     FLIGHT CHECK_SCHEDULE   NEXT_FLIGHT_SCHE
------ ---------- ---------------- ----------------
Boeing        345 10.02.2022 21:00 11.02.2022 04:30
Airbus        789 21.02.2022 16:30 22.02.2022 01:20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need smallest value from `next_flight_schedule` for each aircraft

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT aircraft,
       flight,
       check_schedule,
       next_flight_schedule
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY aircraft
           ORDER BY next_flight_schedule
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  aircraft             VARCHAR2(10),
  flight               NUMBER,
  check_schedule       DATE,
  next_flight_schedule DATE
);

INSERT INTO table_name (aircraft, flight, check_schedule, next_flight_schedule)
  SELECT 'Boeing', 123, TIMESTAMP '2022-02-10 21:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 14:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Boeing', 234, TIMESTAMP '2022-02-10 19:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 22:50:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Boeing', 345, TIMESTAMP '2022-02-10 21:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-11 04:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Airbus', 789, TIMESTAMP '2022-02-21 16:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-22 01:20:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Airbus', 890, TIMESTAMP '2022-02-21 22:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-02-22 02:20:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | AIRCRAFT | FLIGHT | CHECK_SCHEDULE | NEXT_FLIGHT_SCHEDULE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Airbus | 789 | 2022-02-21 16:30:00 | 2022-02-22 01:20:00 |
> | Boeing | 345 | 2022-02-10 21:00:00 | 2022-02-11 04:30:00 |

---

If you want to filter rows to get the earliest `next_flight_schedule` that is also after the maximum `check_schedule` then:

```sql
SELECT aircraft,
       flight,
       check_schedule,
       next_flight_schedule
FROM   (
  SELECT m.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY aircraft
           ORDER BY next_flight_schedule
         ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           MAX(check_schedule) OVER (PARTITION BY aircraft) AS max_check
    FROM   table_name t
  ) m
  WHERE  next_flight_schedule >= max_check
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b5584204412804465d9c7d2da30a67e1)*